# Use CSS in D365 FO HTML Viewer

Tags: html, css, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I have a form, that holds (beside other elements) a HTML Viewer.
This viewer gets input by calling

```
HtmlViewer.parmHtml('theCodeBelow');
```

Sadly, the control ignores the CSS being part of the string.
All I get to see is the plain HTML.

Is there a way to view HTML and CSS in D365 FO inside of a form?

```css
<html> 
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Forum</title> 
<style> .entry{
     display: block;
     height: 100px;
     width: 100%;
}
 .heading{
     background-color: LightSkyBlue;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 2px 0px 2px 2px;
     display: block;
     float: left;
     height: 100%;
     padding: 5px;
    width: 20%;
}
 .content{
     background-color: deepSkyBlue;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 2px 2px 2px 0px;
     display: block;
    float: left;
     height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
     width: 65%;
}
 .autor{
     color: red;
}
 .date{
     color: Green;
     float: right;
}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body> 
 <div class="entry"> 
 <div class="heading"> 
 <span class="autor">Admin</span> 
 <span class,="date">Admin wrote on 2018-09-05T12:05:00:</span> 
 </div> 
 <div class="content">Foo</div> 
 </div> <div class="entry"> 
 <div class="heading"> 
 <span class="autor">Admin</span> 
 <span class,="date">Admin wrote on 2018-09-05T12:07:02:</span> 
 </div> 
 <div class="content">Ba</div>
 </div>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

I am very sorry for the formatting. The HTML/CSS code is generated without any new lines in it so it was afterwards formatted by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve your goal is to use [Extensible controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/user-interface/build-extensible-control) instead of Html Viewer control. Extensible controls support loading CCS and JS files, as well as any other 'resources' you will need.